# Socket.io doesn't emit to clients

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm running my website on a LAN so I can test it while developing. It's actually using PHP for the serverside scripts and NodeJS with Redis and Socket.io to send some data to the clients.

This is what the `server.js` looks like:

```
var express =   require('express'),
http =      require('http'),
server =    http.createServer(app);

var app = express();

const redis =   require('redis');
const io =      require('socket.io');
// The server's redis client
const client =  redis.createClient();

server.listen(3000, '192.168.0.103');

io.listen(server).on('connection', function(socket) {

    const redisClient = redis.createClient();

    // The client's redis client
    redisClient.subscribe('ratings.upvote');
    redisClient.subscribe('followers.newFollower');

    redisClient.on('message', function(channel, message) {
        socket.emit(channel, message);
    });

    client.on('disconnect', function() {
        redisClient.quit();
    });
});
```

The server's address on the LAN is `192.168.0.103` and this is the clientside javascript I'm using to connect to the server:

```
var socket = socketio.connect('192.168.0.103:3000');
socket.set('transports',
    [
        'websocket',
        'flashsocket',
        'htmlfile',
        'xhr-polling',
        'jsonp-polling'
    ]);
socket.set('origins', '*:*');
```

The connections is successful and I don't receive any error message in the JS console in the browser (NodeJS confirms that).

I'm running Redis, Nginx and NodeJS on the same machine and every other machine on the LAN can access the webserver at `http://192.168.0.103`.

**Edit:**

When only the server was running on my local machine and all addresses were set to `127.0.0.1` the Socket.io `emit` was working (server only).